# Why is this Functor instance incorrect?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I've written this code:

```
newtype Pixel a = Pixel (a,a,a) deriving (Show)

instance Functor [Pixel Int] where
    fmap f [] = []
    fmap f [Pixel(a,b,c)] = [Pixel(f a, b, c)]
```

I want the functor to apply to the first element in the `Pixel` type, but I keep getting this error:

```
New.hs:17:18: error:
• Expecting one fewer arguments to ‘[Pixel Int]’
  Expected kind ‘* -> *’, but ‘[Pixel Int]’ has kind ‘*’
• In the first argument of ‘Functor’, namely ‘[Pixel Int]’
  In the instance declaration for ‘Functor [Pixel Int]’
```

I'm pretty lost on this issue, is there any way to apply a functor on an entire list? Or do I need to set up a functor for an individual `Pixel` type and *then* iterate through a list?

Comment: How is the list supposed to be involved here? But yeah, you probably want to have `instance Functor Pixel where`.

Comment: @Ry- I have a list of Pixels in the Pixel format above, I want to be able to change the first value of each Pixel

Comment: I think you shouldn't define any such instance at all. A functor is a parametric container that can contain data _of any type_. WTH is, say, `Pixel (Map String Bool)` supposed to represent? Instead, you should probably introduce a MonoFunctor-style class for pixel base components, [like JuicyPixels does it](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/JuicyPixels-3.2.9.5/docs/Codec-Picture-Types.html#t:Pixel).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I understand, you're given a list of pixels and you want to change the first component (i.e. the red component) of every pixel. Hence, you want the following function:

```hs
changeAllPixels :: [Pixel Int] -> [Pixel Int]
```

**Q:** How do we change every element of a list? **A:** We use `map`:

```hs
changeAllPixels = map changeOnePixel

changeOnePixel :: Pixel Int -> Pixel Int
```

We only want to change the red component. Hence, we have:

```hs
changeOnePixel = changeRedComponent doSomething

changeRedComponent :: (a -> a) -> Pixel a -> Pixel a
changeRedComponent f (Pixel (r, g, b)) = Pixel (f r, g, b)

doSomething :: Int -> Int
```

Now you only  need to implement `doSomething`. For example, if you want to invert the red component then you could implement `doSomething` as follows:

```hs
doSomething x = 255 - x
```

Note that we didn't make `Pixel` an instance of `Functor`. This is because we only want to change the red component and leave the green and blue components alone. We did however use `map` which is the `fmap` for lists.

I think the biggest problem you have is that you don't understand functors well. You should probably spend some time getting acquainted with them.

Comment: Thanks, this made a lot of sense

Answer (score 2):

Actually, `[Pixel Int]` already has an instance of `Functor` because it is a list `[]`. The `Functor` instance for list `[]` is defined in [GHC base](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#map) (it uses the definition of `map`). Now you just need a function that can be applied to each element of that list.

```
fmap show [(Pixel 0 0 0),(Pixel 1 0 0), (Pixel 0 1 0)]
```

`Functor` is generally defined for some container type. It takes a function and applies it to the contents of the container. Then when you call `fmap` on a container that has an instance of `Functor`, the compiler will check that the function can be applied to the elements of that container.

If you are still confused about Functors, I recommend this tutorial: [Functors, Applicatives, And Monads In Pictures](http://adit.io/posts/2013-04-17-functors,_applicatives,_and_monads_in_pictures.html).

Comment: No, `[Pixel Int]` doesn’t have an instance of functor, it has kind `*` where a functor must be `* -> *`.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is a bit off, `fmap` applies a function to a data type and you tell it how. To change values for a list of pixels you would need to map (fmap f) over the list. 
Give this implementation a try.

```
instance Functor Pixel where
    fmap f (Pixel (a,b,c)) = Pixel (f a, b, c)
```

*Edit* this won't work because a,b,c need to be of the same type and functors allow functions of type `a->b`.

As @AlexisKing commented you should use `fmap`, but instead write a function like `mapPixelFirst :: (a -> a) -> Pixel a -> Pixel a`. Then map this function over user list, don't use fmap.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that makes sense. When I try that I get " Couldn't match expected type ‘b’ with actual type ‘a’
      ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          fmap :: forall a b. (a -> b) -> Pixel a -> Pixel b
        at New.hs:18:5-8
      ‘b’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          fmap :: forall a b. (a -> b) -> Pixel a -> Pixel b
        at New.hs:18:5-8 "

Comment: @hdizzle You can’t have a `Functor` instance on `Pixel` that only updates the first field because `Functor` allows changing the type—that is, supplying a function from `Int -> Double` that would change `Pixel Int` to `Pixel Double`—but then if you only apply the function to the first value, you have no way to convert the types of the other two fields.

Comment: @AlexisKing thanks, that makes sense. So then I assume I can define f to change "a" how I want and leave "b" and "c" alone?

Comment: @hdizzle No. There is only one valid `Functor` instance for `Pixel` as defined in your question, and it is `fmap f (Pixel (a, b, c)) = Pixel (f a, f b, f c)`. If you want a function that only adjusts the first element, write a separate function like `mapPixelFirst :: (a -> a) -> Pixel a -> Pixel a`.